# How to create an attributed string for time interval like 3h 32min as seen in Activity app on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to display a timestamp as an attributed string in my iOS app, like we can find on Apple Activity app on iOS 10 (sleep analysis for example) or Fitbit sleep tracking. As you can see on the image below, the units are smaller than the numbers.

Let's say I have time interval in seconds.

I thought about using a [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponentsformatter) and then [localizedString(from:unitsStyle:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1411422-localizedstring) to get the string. But then, I don't know how to turn this string into an attributed one where the unit would be smaller and with a different font color.

I also thought about using [NSMeasurement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmeasurement) + [NSUnitDuration](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/unitduration), and then turn the measurement into a string using a [NSMeasurementFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/measurementformatter). But I run into the same issue: how to separate figures and characters.

Of course, this should work for any language and locale. The ideal would maybe be to extract the numbers and the units, and to apply different style to the different ranges of numbers and "pure" string. Any idea how this could be solved?

[image]

Comment: There is nothing built in. You would have to create an NSAttributedString by finding the range of numbers in the formatted string and applying attributes to that part of the attributed string.

Comment: How would you find the range of numbers? This is the key in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is an .attributedText property on a UILabel. You'll need to create your text like this:

```
    let hoursNumber = 6
    let hoursUnit = "h"
    let minutesNumber = 40
    let minutesUnit = "m"
    let numberFont = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20) ]
    let unitFont = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14) ]
    let timeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(hoursNumber)", attributes: numberFont)
    timeString.append(NSAttributedString(string: hoursUnit, attributes: unitFont))
    timeString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\(minutesNumber)", attributes: numberFont))
    timeString.append((NSAttributedString(string: minutesUnit, attributes: unitFont)))
```

Then set your timeLabel.attributedText = timeString

**EDIT**
... picky, picky ;)

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
    formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    let unitFont = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
    let numberFont = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)]
    let time = formatter.string(from: 300)
    let timeString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    for letter in time!.unicodeScalars {
        let timeLetter : NSAttributedString
        if CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(letter) {
            timeLetter = NSAttributedString(string: "\(letter)", attributes: numberFont)
        } else {
            timeLetter = NSAttributedString(string: "\(letter)", attributes: unitFont)
        }
        timeString.append(timeLetter)
    }
```

Comment: yeah well i deleted mine, this is nothing but perfect...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @zig but this is not ideal as the unit is hard coded and the format is not taking into account the locale of the device.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I was actually looking into CharacterSet. Do you know if decimalDigits contains also Arabic, Japanese, Korean, etc. Characters for numbers? Would your "if" condition to check if the character is a digit or not work for these languages? Thanks!

Comment: @alpennec I believe so. That's one of the benefits of checking the CharacterSet instead of creating your own number array 0...9 and checking that way.